# What is the best thing to uploading multiple images for buy and selling website

Tags: sql, cloud

I'm creating small website for buy and sell, So I need to know what is the best thing for uploading images. I don't have enough money buying cloud storage. I'm beginner with this field.

Answer (score 1):

Well, blob storage is pretty cheap and a suitable candidate for this type of workload.

For Azure, you would use [Azure Blob Storage](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/services/storage/blobs/?&ef_id=Cj0KCQiA-4nuBRCnARIsAHwyuPqTS3mgvg6eHvl4Vn9zpUchJYctZhYzMsStoMjjRWe6drZGlScbuM0aAqsJEALw_wcB:G:s&OCID=AID2000103_SEM_Y7Kb8ZlJ&MarinID=Y7Kb8ZlJ_340830336628_%2Bblob%20%2Bstorage_b_c__62195577063_aud-402620942868:kwd-297823350928&lnkd=Google_Azure_Brand&dclid=CjgKEAiA-4nuBRDdosC5hsSeqn0SJACWntfgH0EC7AG69GtDpzC64ybPIxGO9JkVaJFrMBjhB4WWtPD_BwE). For AWS you would use [AWS S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/?sc_channel=PS&sc_campaign=acquisition_ND&sc_publisher=google&sc_medium=ACQ-P%7CPS-GO%7CBrand%7CDesktop%7CSU%7CStorage%7CS3%7CND%7CEN%7CText&sc_content=s3_e&sc_detail=aws%20s3&sc_category=Storage&sc_segment=293606560749&sc_matchtype=e&sc_country=ND&s_kwcid=AL!4422!3!293606560749!e!!g!!aws%20s3&ef_id=Cj0KCQiA-4nuBRCnARIsAHwyuPrNl3YLQkm7ZlaYi1LEBl_h8qKX3BCiIavd9BBRJzdPrTWdqxti0IEaAqm-EALw_wcB:G:s). Both are highly available, cheap and support direct linking and using CDN services.